# How will I connect my search query to my ionic app?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ionic-framework

I have this query for searching multiple data but it is only static

user_model.php (coeigniter)

```
public function get_halal()
{
    $term = "Buko,Beef,Sugar";
    $terms = explode(',', $term);

    foreach($terms as $term){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('recipe');
    $this->db->join('menu', 'menu.recipe_id = recipe.recipe_id');
    $this->db->join('ingredient', 'ingredient.ingredient_id = menu.ingredient_id');
    $this->db->where('menu.category_id = 2');
    $this->db->like('ingredient.name', $term);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
   }
    return $query;
}
```

I want it to be dynamic and is connected to my ionic app. How would I do that?

Comment: parse `$term` as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

When you think to create a function (or a class), first of all you have to abstract the question to realize how much this function is useful in different context. There are no rules, it's depend on your context and your goals.

In your example, i.e., the function return a database query object for terms "Buko", "Beef" and "Sugar" (*de facto*, only for "Sugar"). If you modify your function in this way:

```
public function get_halal( $what )
```

you can reuse the function to search any terms.

If you modify the function in this way:

```
public function get_halal( $what )
{
    if( is_array($what) ) ...
    else                  ...
```

you can use the same function to search for one or many terms.

If you modify the function in this way:

```
public function get_halal( $what, $where )
```

you can search a term in various field.

There are a lot of possibility, it's the best fun of coding.